# powershell compare two arrays, create third array with only nonmatching values

Tags: powershell

Firstly the only thing I have available is powershell.
I have figured out how to compare two arrays; however, I am having a bit if difficulty figuring out how to get the data back in the format I need.

```
$foo = @(100, 200 ,300 ,400 ,500 ,600 ,700 ,800 ,900 ,1000)
$bar = @(50, 100, 600 , 900)
```

Desired results would be an array with the following information

```
 50, 200, 300, 400, 500, 700, 800, 1000
```

Note that the like values

```
100, 600 , 900
```

are dropped and

```
50
```

which is in the second array is added to the output.

is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Compare-Object is your friend:

```
PS C:\Users> $foo = @(100, 200 ,300 ,400 ,500 ,600 ,700 ,800 ,900 ,1000)
PS C:\Users> $bar = @(50, 100, 600 , 900)
PS C:\Users> Compare-Object $foo $bar -PassThru
50
200
300
400
500
700
800
1000
```

Comment: Ha!  I knew it had to be simple.  Thank you so very much ravikanth

Comment: Welcome! PowerShell is simple! :)